# AWS AppSync: No option to add Lambda resolver

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync, aws-appsync-resolver

I have created an AppSync API and a lambda data source and a resolver to provide data for it. I managed to successfully run queries a couple of days ago.

I wanted to attach a second lambda resolver for a different GraphQL query. I added a new lambda as a data source, but when I click **Attach** in the schema next to the query, I am forwarded to the page for creating a pipeline resolver and there is no way to choose a lambda resolver instead.

Now, even when I just create a new copy of the previous AppSync API with one query and want to attach a lambda resolver to that single query, there is no way to attach a lambda resolver any more. Though it was possible earlier this week. And I can see on old APIs that they are still using lambda resolvers.

Has anything changed on AppSync recently? Or how can I attach a lambda resolver to a query, not a pipeline resolver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the pipeline page opens you select the "Actions" dropdown menu, and then you can choose the "Update runtime" option. Under resolver type you can then choose a Unit type resolver which you are probably looking for.

Something did change, there is a new feature where you can write resolvers using JavaScript and i guess they've put a PIPELINE resolver as the default one.

Comment: Right, forgot to write an answer :D
I connected with the AWS support and they showed me how to do it.

The thing is that the UI experience changed during the week when I played with it.